# Has anyone gotten angular2 working with EaselJS?

Tags: typescript, angular, easeljs

just getting into angular 2 - having trouble figuring out how to get typeScript to access easeljs class system .. any suggestions/fiddles?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your in luck because there are already [type defintions for easeljs](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/easeljs/easeljs.d.ts) in the DefinitelyTyped repo

In order to access the types install typings and then pull the definitions

```
npm install typings --global

typings install dt~easeljs --global --save
```

Edit: updated to reflect the fact that tsd has been deprecated and replaced by tsd

Comment: `tsd` is deprecated. You should be using `typings` https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: Did it work? I have a problem with the import. Could you please provide a step by step with the npm installs and a snippet of the class that instantiates Stage?