# Using Easeljs in Angular2

Tags: angular, easeljs

How exactly can I use easeljs in Angular2?

I have found this question:

[working-with-easeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688166/has-anyone-gotten-angular2-working-with-easeljs)

but the answerer merely states how to install the typings. But then what?

I have roughly the same issue with this blog post:

[adding-typescript-definitions-to-angular2](http://ryanstelmat.com/adding-typescript-declarations-to-angular2-project/)

Again, shows how to add the typings but then what? Do I need to import something?

Here is a simple component that I would like to get working:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
template: `
    <canvas id="demoCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
`
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

    var stage = createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");       
    var circle = createjs.Shape();
    circle.graphics.beginFill("DeepSkyBlue").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
    circle.x = 100;
    circle.y = 100;
    stage.addChild(circle);



}

}
```

But what do I do then?

Comment: Have a look at this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989399/do-i-have-to-reference-typescript-definition-in-every-file

Comment: I checked the answer above, but did not figure out how to do it right.
Do you have a checklist, WHICH file to include in the files array in tsconfig.json???
Did that solve your problems? I run into a Stage is not a constructor error, but I have no clue if that is connected to the above problem (I guess so).